# Delete rows with certain magnitude datetime difference

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that looks something like the following:

```
| ID | Value |        Date          |
|----|-------|----------------------|
| 4  |   9   | 4/14/2021 3:00:00 PM |
| 4  |   1   | 4/14/2021 4:00:00 PM |
| 4  |   3   | 4/14/2021 4:03:00 PM |
| 4  |   2   | 4/14/2021 4:05:00 PM |
| 2  |  50   | 4/14/2021 4:00:00 PM |
| 2  |  20   | 4/14/2021 4:10:00 PM |
```

What I would like to do is delete any rows for each ID that are within a certain time magnitude from each other, for this example lets say 5 minutes, while keeping the most recent record. Using the example table the expected output would be the following

```
| ID | Value |        Date          |
|----|-------|----------------------|
| 4  |   9   | 4/14/2021 3:00:00 PM |
| 4  |   2   | 4/14/2021 4:05:00 PM |
| 2  |  50   | 4/14/2021 4:00:00 PM |
| 2  |  20   | 4/14/2021 4:10:00 PM |
```

This is for MS Access

Comment: I don't have an answer (off the top of my head), but a general SQL solution might be difficult to port over to Access, which does not support analytic functions.

Comment: Very easy in VBA, may be not even possible in Access SQL.

Comment: I will take VBA if you have a solution.

Comment: What if you had 10 rows in a row one minute apart?  What results would you want?

Comment: 9 would get deleted and the newest 10th row would be kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following produces desired output with given sample.

Query1:

```
SELECT Table1.*, (
    SELECT TOP 1 Dup.Dte FROM Table1 AS Dup WHERE Dup.GrpID=Table1.GrpID AND 
    Dup.ID>Table1.ID ORDER BY Dte) AS NextDte
FROM Table1;
```

Query2 - If you really want to delete records and not just filter:

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Query1 WHERE DateDiff("n",[Dte],[NextDte])<=5);
```

Notice this requires a unique identifier field (or compound unique identifier) - autonumber field should serve. I used ID for that field and GrpID for each group ID. Value and Date are reserved words so I used different names.

Comment: Appears to be working great! Thanks for the help!